# Icon in the Systray of odoo 16 with badge and click to function

Tags: odoo

I am doing a course project in Odoo 16 and I need to show an icon in the systray with a badge that shows the number of existing notifications and when I click on them, they are displayed. I have followed the tutorial "How to Add an Icon in Systray in Odoo 16" by [cybrosys] (https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/how-to-add-an-icon-in-systray-in-odoo-16) but I don't know how to show a badge with a value obtained from a function nor how to link the click of the icon to a specific function of a model that shows the notifications. This is the code that I have made from the cybrosys tutorial in which I want to call the "_len_notifications" function of the notifications model and show its result in a badge and when clicking on the icon the "_show_notifications" function of the same model, the problem is that it is not working for me, the icon is displayed but it does not do any of the two things, please help:

view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<templates xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-name="systray_icon" owl="1">
        <div class="">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" title="Notifications" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="o_MessagingMenu_icon fa fa-bell" role="img" aria-label="Notifications"></i>
                    <span class="badge" id="notification_badge"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </t>
</templates>
```

JS

```
import { registry } from "@web/core/registry";
import { useService } from "@web/core/utils/hooks";
import { Component } from "@odoo/owl";

class SystrayIcon extends Component { 
    setup() {
        super.setup(...arguments);
        this.action = useService("action"); 
        this.rpc = require('web.rpc');
    }
    _onClick() {
        
        // this.action.doAction({
        //     type: "ir.actions.act_window",
        //     name: Notifications",
        //     res_model: "notification.notification",
        //     view_mode: "form",
        //     views: [[false, "form"]],
        //     target: "new",
        // });

        this.rpc.query({
            model: "notification.notification",
            method: "_show_notifications",
        }).then(function () {});
    }

    this.rpc.query({
        model: "notification.notification",
        method: "_len_notifications",
    }).then(function (result) {
        document.getElementById("notification_badge").innerHTML = result;
    });
}
SystrayIcon.template = "systray_icon";
export const systrayItem = { Component: SystrayIcon,};
registry.category("systray").add("SystrayIcon", systrayItem, { sequence: 1 });
```

**manifest**.py

```
'assets': {
    'web.assets_backend': [
        'project_course/static/src/js/systray_icon.js',
        'project_course/static/src/xml/systray_icon.xml',],
    },
```

Notifications model

```
from odoo import api, fields, models

class Notification(models.Model):
    _name = 'notification.notification'
    _description = 'Notification Model'
    
    user_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.users', string='User', required=True)
    message = fields.Char(string='Message', required=True)
    status = fields.Selection(string="Status", default="send" selection=[('send', 'send'), ('read', 'read')],)
    
    @api.model
    def _show_notifications(self):
        notifications = self.env[self._name].search([('user_id', '=', self.env.uid), ('status', '=', 'send')])
        if len(notifications) != 0:
            for n in notifications:
                self.env.user.notify_info(message = n.message)
            notifications.write({'status': 'read'})
        else:
            self.env.user.notify_warning(message="There are no notifications")

    @api.model
    def _len_notifications(self):
        notifications = self.env[self._name].search([('user_id', '=', self.env.uid), ('status', '=', 'send')])
        return len(notifications)
```

Please help me, I would be very grateful, thank you.

Comment: Private methods (such as `_len_notifications`) cannot be called remotely